# GetScript для больших библиотек

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Загружаю несколько библиотек на js с помощью getScript, все вроде бы хорошо, но как дело доходит до загрузки библиотеки размером 400 кб, то метод просто ничего не делает, даже не вызывает callback. Такая же история с загрузкой через ajax

```
function getScriptAjax( url, callback ) {
    callback = (typeof callback != 'undefined') ? callback : {};

    jQuery.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: url,
         success: callback,
         dataType: "script",
         cache: true
     });
```

}

Comment: Кстати, в jquery есть готовая функция $.getScript

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли проблема в jquery. Посмотрите в логи веб-сервера.

**Обновление**

Возможно three.js не был загружен на момент загрузки/встраивания в страницу проблемного файла.

**Обновление 2**

Не смешивайте, статус 200 вам вернул веб-сервер, а ошибка у вас на этапе встраивания кода на страницу.

Существует много вариантов решить проблему: можете в своём скрипте ждать пока будет `defined window[THREE]`, можете загружать свой скрипт в callback-е загрузки `three.js`, можете слить эти файлы в один, можете использовать для загрузки что-то типа `curl.js` и т.д.

Comment: И правда, дело не в размере))

При загрузке через AJAX выбивает parseerror, но пока не нашел причину этого, файл с функциями ничем особенным не отличает от остальных... сейчас кодировку проверю

Comment: значит отличается. неужели нет никаких проблем при подключении этого скрипта на страницу с помощью тега script?

Comment: через тег нет проблем.
parseerror из-за того, что в скрипте содержатся обращения к three.js, который до этого был загружен таким же методом, но ругается именно при наличии пространства имени THREE

Comment: скорее всего так и есть.. но getSCript вернул статус 200, то есть успешно загружено, но тем не менее успешно загруженную библиотеку не видит